# TextField display issue in Codenameone when text is larger than the TextField area

Tags: codenameone

If TextField text is larger than the TextField area on the screen, the text displayed by default does not reflect the start of the text until.

Here is a code from a fresh project:

```
 Form hi = new Form("Hi World", BoxLayout.y());
 hi.add(new Label("Hi World"));
 hi.add(new TextField("A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z"));
 hi.show();
```

In the example above, I expected to see the text displayed below to start with

> A B C D ...

as opposed to

> E F G H ...

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `TextField` shows the text in the position of the cursor which is positioned at the end of the input by default. You can workaround this by setting the cursor position to 0 but I'm guessing it's not what you want.

I think it makes sense to have an option to draw the text field in this way when it isn't focused so feel free to file an RFE for that although I'm not sure when we'll get around to it.

Notice it should be pretty easy to add an option to DefaultLookAndFeel.java under `drawTextField` if you are interested in [submitting a pull request](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/how-to-use-the-codename-one-sources.html).